# Importing external modules under a namespace in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a collection of modules that aimed at working with UI, so this is what it looks like in terms of folders:

```
ui/
  dialogs.ts
  tabs.ts
  progress-bar.ts
  menus.ts
```

I would like to import these modules under a namespace so instead of doing:

```
import uiDialogs = require('ui/dialogs');
import uiMenus = require('ui/menus');
```

I wish I could do something like this:

```
import ui { 
  dialogs: require('ui/dialogs'),
  menus: require('ui/menus')
}
```

Is there a way to do this in TypeScript?

Comment: What about ``import foo = ... import bar = ...  var ui = { foo: foo, bar: bar };``

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to do this directly in TypeScript. The code gen for AMD modules doesn't really lend itself to this -- the module names come in at the top level, so the compiler would have to magic up a name to use for you.

You can emulate the behavior the compiler would have to do to accomplish that, though:

```
import __k = require('ko');
module imports {
    export import ko = __k;
}
var x = imports.ko.whatever;
```

Comment: this method only works for types defined in the sub-modules, that is `imports.ko.whatever` can only be used in a context where a type is expected, if used in the body of a function the TypeScript complaints `Cound not find symbol 'imports'`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
import dialogs = require('ui/dialogs');
import menus = require('ui/menus');

var ui = {dialogs: dialogs, menus: menus};
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you create an index.ts inside `ui` folder:

```
ui/
  dialogs.ts
  tabs.ts
  progress-bar.ts
  menus.ts
  index.ts
```

with content like:

```
import uiDialogs = require('ui/dialogs');
export var dialogs = uiDialogs;
import uiMenus = require('ui/menus');
export var menus = uiMenus;
```

and usage:

```
import ui = require('ui/index');
```

Also this is the pattern recommended under nodejs. You can vote for a related TypeScript feature here : https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2125 where you do not even need to type in `/index` since that is already assumed by nodejs. TypeScript could easily code gen consistently for both node/amd.

Comment: An edit to this post included some information that should have been in a comment. I rolled it back but you may wish to review the original intent (regarding `var`) and update if you see fit.

Comment: this whole idea didn't workout, when I use `import` I cannot access the functions from sub-modules, when I use `var` I cannot access the types, when I use both: `export import Dialogs = uiDialogs` for types and `export var dialogs = uiDialogs` for functions it works but having 2 separate namespaces for functions and types is a killer.

Comment: @1365 don't recommend using "internal" modules when you are already using external modules : www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Basarat, as far as I can tell I am not mixing internal modules with the external ones.